# VB.NET SQL Error Delete statement

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

An error "Incorrect Syntax near uig." keeps popping up and I've looked up several SQL Delete queries and mine don't seem to have any major differences in terms of syntax. I might've really overlooked something and not sure if it might be related, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

```
query = "IF EXISTS(SELECT uig.group_id FROM useringroup uig JOIN Users u ON uig.user_id = u.user_id JOIN accessgrouptbl ag ON uig.group_id = ag.group_id 
WHERE u.user_csn = '" & GV.userCSN & "' AND ag.group_name = '" & value2 & "') 
DELETE FROM useringroup uig JOIN accessgrouptbl ag ON uig.group_id = ag.group_id 
WHERE ag.group_name = '" & value2 & "'"
```

P.S. The EXISTS condition does not have any issues as I used the same condition for an insert query and it worked fine hence I assumed the error to be on the Delete statement.

Comment: First, stop using string concatenation to insert values into SQL code and use parameters instead. That can solve a lot of formatting issues and the like that can cause syntax errors. If you still have an issue, rewrite your VB code so that the SQL code is easy to read, which means using an XML literal or a multi-line string literal. That can often make issues obvious.

Comment: Also, does the SQL you want to execute work in Management Studio?

Comment: Ok I'll try using parameters instead. How do I try executing it in Management Studio?

Comment: If you want to work with SQL Server then you pretty much have to know how to use SQL Server Management Studio but this is not the place to learn the basics of that.  Download and install it if you don't already have it, open it up and see what you can do and then search the web for information on how to do what you can't. Executing a query is pretty much the most basic operation in any database management client, so not hard to find out.

Comment: I already have it downloaded and currently using it to see my database values/updates/changes when i execute and test my program using visual studio, just that I've never thought of directly executing a SQL inside Management Studio. Are there any benefits of executing a SQL inside Management Studio rather than through VS?

Comment: Particularly for complex SQL, it can often be a good idea to start off in SSMS because you get more immediate feedback.  It can be easier to break a query down and build it up in parts to see in which part a problem occurs, then just copy the final product to your VB project.  There may be some small edits required between the two, e.g. semicolons between statements in a `SqlCommand` but for the most part it will just be copy and paste.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Not sure why I'm not allowed to use Aliases for the delete statement, but it worked when i did this

```
DELETE FROM useringroup 
WHERE group_id = (SELECT group_id FROM accessgrouptbl 
WHERE group_name = @value)
```